# Is Google Play unofficial API rate-limited?

Tags: android, google-play

I 've been using Google Play unofficial API (via https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api) for a while to collect stats on specific applications.

It has been working perfectly fine until recently that I get an HTML page reading:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. 
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests,
>   and not a robot.

So it seems Google have rate-limited their unofficial API.

My question is twofold:

1. I 'd like to confirm rate limits are indeed imposed;
2. I wanted to ask if anyone is aware of what those limits might be, e.g. how may requests are allowed per minute before raising an alarm.

Cheers,

Comment: You might better ask on the github page of that API.

Comment: @L.Butz I only added the name of the library as a reference. My question is really about the Google Play unofficial API and should apply to everyone using that API, independent of library used.